# How do I embed an open-source project in a django project for GAE?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, open-source, inclusion

I am a python newbie. Can anybody tell me how I will be embed an open-source project in my django project for GAE? Let's say I would like to embed [Python markdown](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/). Can anybody show me a direction? Can I just copy and paste my source into my django folder and modify something in the settings.py to get it done?

The reason for embedding the source is that GAE does not allow egg files running in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply unzip the contents of the folder inside the .egg archive which is *not* named EGG-INFO to your application folder.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you are inteding to use the python version of appengine, for every external library that you want to deploy with your application, except from importing in my own experience when I recently had to use external libraries they weren't working in the online version unless I had them to the root folder of my app.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can place the module in the python-path and import it wherever you need in your django code? Or is this not what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Tipfy and see how they handle dependencies. You can probably use the same techniques in Django.

http://www.tipfy.org/